# Get an error while i try to put Insterstitial Ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

i ask here because i can't put instertital ads in my app. I get like 20 errors when i put the code below the saved Instance.
I had other app and i never had problems, but now i just can't.

In the section of Toast (below ad code) i get this error: 
    Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "(", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    - Syntax error on token "makeText", Identifier expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

Below toast, on btnSwitch i get this errors:
    Multiple markers at this line
    - Return type for the method is missing
    - Syntax error on token ".", ... expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token
    - Syntax error on token "btnSwitch", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration

package lol.flashlight;

Then here:

```
ImageView Facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    Facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
```

i get this errors:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     MethodBody
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody

**...I get MORE errors
I tried to put it at the final but anyway i get these errors, what can i do?
I let my full code if u wanna check:**

```
import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {

ImageView btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

private InterstitialAd interstitial;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "fgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg");

    // Create ad request
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    // Begin loading your interstitial
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }

@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Touch amumu's body to play a sound!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not        
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    } 


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    ImageView Facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    Facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.draven);

                                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        mp.release();
                                    }
                                }); 

                                mp.start();

                                Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                                facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lol.flashlight");
                                startActivity(facebookIntent);

                            }});



    ImageView Twitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    Twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.draven);

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            }); 

            mp.start();
            //al apretar click en el boton Ir a Web abre el browser con la pág: google.com
            Intent browserIntent = 
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lol.flashlight%20-%20This%20app%20is%20amazing,%20i%20love%20it!"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);




            }});

    //OnClick del View :D
    ImageView Ez = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Ez.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.amumu);

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 

    mp.start();
    }});  




  //OnClick del View :D
//    ImageView Mundo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
//    Mundo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

//  public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      
    //  mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mundo);

    //mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

      //  @Override
    //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //  mp.release();
    //    }
  //  }); 

   // mp.start();
    //}});  




    //OnClick del View :D
 //   ImageView Orianna = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
   // Orianna.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    //public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.orianna);

   // mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

     //   @Override
   //     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //     mp.release();
      //  }
   // }); 

   // mp.start();
    //}});  





    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}


// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }


 // Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}


 // Playing sound
 // will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
private void playSound(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playbutton);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rayo);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 
    mp.start();
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;


    }


}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your imports here are wrong, because they import from **legacy admob**:

```
import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;
```

You have to import from `.gms` **Google Play Services Admob**:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
```

---

Also note that all the code below `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Touch amumu's body to play a sound!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in your example is **outside of any method** (!) ..this is causing the dozens of compile errors. ==> move that code into some method

Comment: yeah i know it's from legacy admob (its the oldier right?)  but i couldn't put the new Ads. I updated my eclipse because i needed it to put Google play services admob, but i get an error in eclipse when i try to use it, so i uninstalled eclipse and started again like before with old ads and fu** it. I am newbie so i can't do so much, i read that so many people got this problem.

Comment: well i tried deleting "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Touch amumu's body to play a sound!" 
But anyway i still have tons of errors (the same quantity).. I dont  know what can be.. :|

Comment: forget it. You know what was my error?

// Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "my ID");

    // Create ad request
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    // Begin loading your interstitial
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
  }  <<<<<------------ THIS ONE THING, i was "closing" the saved stance letting code out of it. Hope u understand :D